# What is the proper name for this vintage "traditional folding gate door"?

Tags: vocabulary, image-identification

Could anyone tell me what is the correct or better name for this gate/door?

They are usually used by old shops in Asian countries (possibly from 1940s to 1960s).

The photo is on this [web-page](https://www.123rf.com/photo_105143064_traditional-folding-gate-door-that-usually-found-on-asian-shop-houses.html).

[image: large rusty-looking folding window frames]

Comment: [***Retractable / folding security grilles**?*](https://securitydirectuk.com/retractable-folding-grilles/)

Answer (score 2):

The Japanese variation of these are known as a *folding shoji screen*.

In Japanese, a 'shoji' is a wooden sliding door with translucent paper on, so a 'folding shoji' is a variation of that. I see your photo doesn't have the paper on it though.

In British English, a similar piece of furniture is known as a *room divider*. I see that on various online stores they advertise "Asian/Oriental Screens & Room Dividers", so perhaps that is the default descriptive name used, as 'shoji' is probably not widely known.

Comment: I've also seen them called Bifolding doors (even when there's more than 2 sections) or Roomfold doors.

Comment: A _freestanding_ piece of furniture like that was traditionally called a (folding) screen in British English. My parents had a _fitted_ room divider in their 1970s bungalow (zigzag like the picture, but made of wood) which we called 'folding doors'.

Comment: My aunt and uncle had one in their 1950s semi in Orpington. They called it a 'folding divider'.